# Django - How to load javascript variable from another file to template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

How can I load some variable from another js document inside a template, and then modify this variable inside a script tag in my template?

For example:

**js file**

```
let myObject = {color: red}
```

**Django template**

```
{% extends 'app/general/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 id="color"></h1>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('color').innerHTML = myObject.color //I need some way of loading myObject here, and be able to retrieve and edit data from it
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simple.

```
<script src="path_to_your_file.js"></script>
<script>        
    console.log(myObject);
</script>
```

Where `path_to_your_file.js` is the path to the file where the `myObject` is present

Comment: I just console logged the object here just to show how to do that. You can now do whatever you want with that object

Comment: That is not working. [link](https://imgur.com/uG0smfX)

Comment: chartObject is an object inside the file 'chart-area-demo.js'

Comment: The problem was that my cache was not clear. I had to do a ctrl + F5 to be able to apply the changes.

Comment: This is the way how we plugin the external js into our templates.